# Тире или дефис в предложениях?

Tags: орфография, тире

Правильно ли в этих в двух предложениях поставлены тире и дефис?

Кран шаровой серия «B» внутренняя-наружная резьба, рукоятка — «бабочка».
Кран шаровой серия «B» внутренняя-наружная резьба, рукоятка — рычаг.

Comment: "Внутренняя-наружная" означает, что резьба и внутренняя, и наружная одновременно или это переходник с внутренней резьбы на наружную.. Разве есть такие краны?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написал так:

"Кран шаровой серия «B» внутренняя/наружная резьба, рукоятка — «бабочка»"

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях используется дефис или косая черта (слеш).

Пример с картинкой:

Кран шаровой серия «B»
**внутренняя-наружная** резьба, рукоятка — рычаг

https://miraya.world/ru/lever-ball-valve-fxm-b-series/

**Косая черта или дефис в ПАС**: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=60#pp60